# Frequency Table by user in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

Very basic SQL question (DB is MySQL):

I want a table of number of transactions by users.

```
User ID   Transaction count
1         43
2         213
3         0
4         23
5         0
```

In a table I have the two relevant records (user_id and buy_count).

How could I get the table I want?

Thanks,

Roberto

Answer (score 2):

[Group By](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum)

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(buy_count)
FROM table
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: I tried doing that, I get an error message "Cross-database references are not implemented". Strange as user_id is indeed in the table where buy_count is. Ideas?

Comment: @Roberto: Can you amend your question with the tables and their columns? It would help durilai to write a query that uses specifics. (This may sound obvious but you used your table name in place of `table` didn't you?)

Comment: @Roberto, you did not specify a table name, so I just used 'table'. See @JYelton comment. I have the most basic syntax there, so update your question and I wil give you an exact query to run.